# Export HTML table to excel in safari

Tags: angularjs, safari, filesaver.js

Is there anyway to export HTML table to Excel in Safari? 
I am using FileSaver.js --> SaveAs (XLS) for now which works great in Chrome, But I wanna know something in SAFARI please? I am happy to use any other Liberary then filesaver.js